# How to get back focus on the input text after soft keyboard hidden (Mobile App)

Tags: cordova, mobile, kendo-ui

I have a mobile app, which creates profile. Tapping the input text box brings up the soft keyboard, once done keying in the text, i click hide / done button in the soft keypad. But the focus goes out of the text box. For visually enabled users its ok, he/she can just tap the next element.

But this is a problem for blind users. (I have to make the app accessible for visually disabled/blind users.I have used ARIA/Html 5 for that purpose and it works great except this problem)

How to keep the focus back on the element after the soft keypad is hidden. 
 Thanks in advance for any help.